# Android memory leak in an inner class

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

In my Android app, I have a splash screen and then comes a login screen. After the user logs in, they land on a welcome screen. My app crashes a lot on Samsung Galaxy S3 so I decided to look this up in MAT.

I took the heap dump on the welcome screen, and it is showing the splash object in memory. I have posted the code below. What could be causing this memory leak?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashActivity extends CoreActivity implements ConnectionCallBack{

    private static final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int LOGIN_SCREEN = 0;
    protected static final String SPL = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int SHOW_MESSAGE = 1;
    private Timer timer;
    private TextView connectionNotificationTV;
    private int notificationCount = 0;
    private Handler handler;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        Globals.appContext = getApplicationContext();

        connectionNotificationTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_connection_notification_TV);

        handler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(msg.what == SHOW_MESSAGE){
                    if(notificationCount == 0){
                        connectionNotificationTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(notificationCount == 1){
                        confirmationDialog();
                    }
                    notificationCount++;
                }else if(msg.what == LOGIN_SCREEN){
                    loadNext(LOGIN_SCREEN);
                }
            };
        };
        LocationDisplay location = new LocationDisplay(getApplicationContext());   

        ConnectionCheckThread newConnectionThread = new ConnectionCheckThread(this);
        newConnectionThread.start();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(notificationCount == 0){
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }, 30000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Utils.unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.root));
    }

    private void setScreenDimension(){
      int  screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
       int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
       GeneralSettings.getInstance().setScreenHeight(screenHeight);
       GeneralSettings.getInstance().setScreenWidth(screenWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            System.exit(0);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void confirmationDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.connection_error_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.connection_error_message);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.connection_error_close_btn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void loadNext(int code) {
        if(code == LOGIN_SCREEN){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void loadPrev() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedConnection(int returnCode) {
        if(returnCode == ConnectionCheckThread.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT ||
           returnCode == ConnectionCheckThread.UNKNOWN_HOST ||
           returnCode == ConnectionCheckThread.UNKNOWN_ERROR){
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_MESSAGE);
        }else if(returnCode == ConnectionCheckThread.CONNECTION_SUCCESS){
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(LOGIN_SCREEN);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the thread class:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;

public class ConnectionCheckThread extends Thread{

    private static final String TAG = ConnectionCheckThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private ConnectionCallBack callback;
    //private HttpURLConnection http = null;
    //private InputStream is;
    //private boolean isFirstTime = true;
    public static int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 200;
    public static int UNKNOWN_HOST = 201;
    public static int UNKNOWN_ERROR = 202;
    public static int CONNECTION_SUCCESS = 203;
    public static int CONNECTION_FAILURE = 204;
//  private int returnCode;
//  private int retryCount = 0;
    Context context;

    public ConnectionCheckThread(Context con){
        this.context = con;
        this.callback = (ConnectionCallBack)con;
    }


    public void run(){
        HttpURLConnection http = null;
        boolean isFirstTime = true;
        String urlString = "http://www.google.com/";
        int returnCode = 0;
        int retryCount = 0;

        do{

            try {
                URL urls = new URL(urlString);

                http = (HttpURLConnection)urls.openConnection();

                int responsecode = http.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("responsecode = "+responsecode);

                if(isFirstTime){
                    http.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                }else{
                    http.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                }

                http.connect();
                InputStream is = http.getInputStream();

                returnCode = CONNECTION_SUCCESS;
            } catch (java.net.SocketException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Utils.log(TAG, "caught SocketException[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
                returnCode = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
            } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ex) { 
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Utils.log(TAG, "caught SocketTimeoutException[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
                returnCode = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
            } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Utils.log(TAG, "caught UnknownHostException[" + ex.getMessage() + "]");
                returnCode = UNKNOWN_HOST;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Utils.log(TAG, "Exception in WebRequest Thread :" + e.getMessage());
                returnCode = UNKNOWN_ERROR;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (http != null) {
                        http.disconnect();
                        http = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                callback.onReceivedConnection(returnCode);
                if(retryCount == 0){
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
                retryCount++;
            }
        }while(retryCount <= 1 && returnCode != CONNECTION_SUCCESS);
    }

    Handler handler2 = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == CONNECTION_FAILURE){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.login_no_network_title));
                alert.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.login_no_network_content));
                alert.show();
            }

        };
    };
}
```

Comment: do you need System.exit(0)? why not use finish(). I guess because you are storing context variable in thread, the activity might be leaking. Can you try by making null the context in thread as soon as run is over

Comment: Sunny - do you need to see the logcat or the MAT output?

Comment: Thank you Nandeesh. So inside the run() method, do I just say this.context = null after the return code is populated?

Comment: Are you using the CONNECTION_FAILURE dialog? because otherwise do not store the context item at all and you ccan easily move the alert dialog to the activity rather than thread where it belongs

Comment: Nandeesh - Yes, I am using the connection_failure dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the Handler a static class instead of an anonymous class. I think the SplashActivity must be kept by a android.os.Message and Handler. The Handler keeps a reference to the enclosing SplashActivity. If it's not the problem, please paste a snapshot after query 'select * from instanceof android.app.Activity' and the 'path to GC'.